# Как выровнять input по центру?

Tags: html, css, css3

не получается выровнять по центру форму. Уже всё попробовал. Flex использовать не вариант. Так же не получается сделать кнопку по ширине input-ов или тоже разместить по центру.

```css
form {
 display: block;
 background: #5B3C67;
 padding: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 color: white;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

form input {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 //margin-left: 40%;
 width: 23%;
 height: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ff8c00;
}

.button {
 width: 20%;
 font-size: 14pt;
 color: white;
 background: #7F113E;
 height: 55px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #F5C4AB;
}

.button:hover {
 border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<section class="order">

   <div class="center">

    <form class="" action="send.php" method="post">
     <h1>Свяжитесь с нами</h1>
     <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя" required><br>
     <input type="text" name="email" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required><br>
     <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required><br>
     
     <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Отправить"><br>

    </form>

   </div>

  </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

не нужно добавлять у самих input-ов text-align:center, полезнее у родителя:

```
form {text-align:center;}
```

по поводу одинаковой ширины - определить у input и button

```
width: 25%;
```

только еще у input добавить

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

чтобы padding не влияли на ширину

```css
form {
  display: block;
  background: #5B3C67;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  //margin-left: 40%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8c00;
}

.button {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  background: #7F113E;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #F5C4AB;
}

.button:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<section class="order">

  <div class="center">

    <form class="" action="send.php" method="post">
      <h1>Свяжитесь с нами</h1>
      <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required><br>

      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Отправить"><br>

    </form>

  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

С flex

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
form {
 background: #5B3C67;
 padding: 50px;
 color: white;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form input {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 //margin-left: 40%;
 width: 23%;
 height: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ff8c00;
  width: 150px;
}

.button {
 width: 20%;
 font-size: 14pt;
 color: white;
 background: #7F113E;
 height: 55px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #F5C4AB;
  width: 200px;
}

.button:hover {
 border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<section class="order">

   <div class="center">

    <form class="" action="send.php" method="post">
     <h1>Свяжитесь с нами</h1>
     <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя" required><br>
     <input type="text" name="email" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required><br>
     <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required><br>
     
     <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Отправить"><br>

    </form>

   </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: Тоже как вариант, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. Надо было добавить:

```css
form input {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Можно просто `margin: auto;` ...